# Definite Integral of Kronecker product of matrices

Tags: matrices, definite-integrals, matrix-calculus, kronecker-product

How to prove:  $$\int_k^{k+1}\int_k^{k+1}  (A⊗B) dxdy = \int_k^{k+1}\int_k^{k+1} A    dx⊗\int_k^{k+1}\int_k^{k+1} Bdy $$, where k is an integer and A and B are matrices  consisting of variables x and y respectively.

Comment: Please, use proper Latex.

Answer (score 1):

Since $(A,B)\rightarrow A\bigotimes B$ is bilinear, one has $\int_k^{k+1}\int_k^{k+1}  (A⊗B) dxdy =\int_k^{k+1} A (x)dx⊗\int_k^{k+1} B(y)dy $.

EDIT. More generally $\int_{(x,y)\in [a,b]\times [c,d]} ( A(x)⊗B(y)) dxdy =\int_a^b A (x)dx⊗\int_c^d B(y)dy $.